# is a given array a sub sequence of another array

Tags: c, arrays, nested-loops

building a code that will check if a group of numbers in `s_array[]` is a sub-sequence of `array[]`, that means that `{ 1, 5, 4 }` is not a sub-sequence of `array`, whereas `{ 1, 4, 5}` is one (order matters)

my code will first check if the first element of `s_array[]` exists in `array[]`, once a common element is found it will proceed to check if the rest of `s_array[]`'s elements also exist in `array[]` and in the same order (other elements can be between them)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int s_array[] = { 5, 7, 13 };
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    int i, Bcount, m, counter = 1, j = 4;
    //i, Bcount and m are loop counters
    //counter will count number of repeated elements
    //j is the number of elements in s_array + 1

    for( i = 0; i <= 15; i++ ){
        if( s_array[0] == array[i] ){ // does the first element exist?
            for( Bcount = 1; Bcount < j; Bcount++ ){ //checking the rest 
                for( m = i; m < 15; m++){
                    if( s_array[Bcount] == array[m] ){
                        counter++;
                        i = m;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if( j == counter ){
               printf( "B is a sub-sequence of A.\n" );
               break;
        }
        else{
               printf( "B is not a sub-sequence of A.\n" );
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

and honestly I can't see if it is the algorithm or that I did something wrong with the coding

Comment: What is the question? How do you define `sub-sequence of array`? -- Do you know that you can build sentences in English starting with capital letter and end with period?

Comment: Split it to pieces. Let's say you're looking for subsequence S in array A. First, you need to find if S[0] is in A. If it is, then you need to find if S[1] is in the _the rest of_ A, i.e. one of A[x] where x > position of S[0] in A. Then you need to find S[2] in the rest, and ... There's a rather simple recursion here, which translates quite simply into a loop in the code.

Comment: What are the `break` statements for. Look superfluous til dangerous here.

Comment: (I took the assumption that by "S is subsequence of A" you mean "all items in S also appear in A, in the same order, but need not be contiguous". Well, that seems to be [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence), too, though there's a slight danger of confusing it with a contiguous subsequence.)

Comment: @Ahmad Khateeb  Just change the tag from C to C++ and use standard algorithm std::includes.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the first loop is wrong as `i` goes up to `15` and at this index you access `array` out of bounds (undefined behavior).

Then the loop is quite simple. You only need

- one loop `i` index for array and `si` for s_array
- only increment `si` if you find the number `array[i]` at `s_array[si]`
- stop the loop if `i` covered `array`, *or* if `si` got the number of sub array elements (3)
- if `si` is at least 3, the sub sequence was found

That is

```
int s_array[] = { 5, 7, 13 };
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

 int si,i;
 for (si=0,i=0 ; i<15 && si<3 ; i++) {
    if (s_array[si] == array[i]) si++;
 }

 printf ("Sub was %s\n", si<3 ? "not found":"found");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the problem is that the loop get's terminated by the outer if condition:

```
    if( j == counter ){
           printf( "B is a sub-sequence of A.\n" );
           break;
    }
    else{
           printf( "B is not a sub-sequence of A.\n" );
           break;
    }
```

after the first loop cycle, the program checks this condition and breaks.
This condition should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Should J not be equal to 3 and the first fot loop index to 14 (or make it strictly less than 15 rather than less than or equal to)? In your second for loop j may be equal to 3 and s_array[3] is invalid. I would try something like:

```
Bcount = 0;
counter = 1;
for( i = 0; i <= 14; i++ ){
    if( s_array[Bcount] == array[i] ){
        counter++;
        Bcount++;
        if(counter == 3){
              printf("Success");
              break;
        }
    }
}
```